# Assign pagination from function

Tags: smarty

Can someone please tell me how I can return pagination results to a template through a function instead of assigning it directly to a template.

I can get the data returned ok using

```
$return_vars['$results'] =  array_slice($results, SmartyPaginate::getCurrentIndex(),SmartyPaginate::getLimit());
```

But i cant seem to get the other information like

```
{* display pagination header *}
    Items {$paginate.first}-{$paginate.last} out of {$paginate.total} displayed.
{* display pagination info *}
    {paginate_prev} {paginate_middle} {paginate_next}
```

I think basically instead of

```
// assign {$paginate} var
SmartyPaginate::assign($smarty);
// display results
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

I need something like

```
$return_vars['pagination'] = SmartyPaginate::assign($smarty);
```

but the array returned is empty

Answer (score 0):

In case anyones interested in the future I got the information by typecasting the smarty object to an array and then returning the paginate part of the array.

```
$tmp_paginate = (array) $smarty;
$return_vars['pagination'] = $tmp_paginate['_tpl_vars']['paginate'];
```

Now I can assign $return_vars['pagination'] to $paginate in the template